# A proof based on structural induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the fact that all $x\in\{0,1\}$, how to prove by structural induction that $\lambda x=x$.

I am struggling with the inductive step of this proof. Can somebody give me some hints?

Comment: Hi, welcome.  It's not exactly clear what your question is about.  What is $\{0,1\}*$ in the first place?  What is $\lambda$?

Comment: Is $\{0,1\}^*$ the set of binary strings?  Is $\lambda$ the empty string?

Comment: Induction is not needed unless you want to prove it the hard way.